# Why does the clk not appear on the device under test?

Tags: vhdl

The clk signal is not being provided to the device under test from the test bench. I am unable to find the issue. It simply outputs 'U'.

**What could be the issue?**

[image]

**The current output**

Testbench for counterEx

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counterEx_tb is
end counterEx_tb;

architecture arch of counterEx_tb is
    constant M : integer := 10;
    constant N : integer := 4;
    constant T : time := 20 ns; 

    signal clk, reset : std_logic;  -- input
begin

    unit : entity work.counterEx
        generic map (M => M, N => N)
        port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset);

    -- continuous clock
    process 
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for T/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for T/2;
    end process;


    -- reset = 1 for first clock cycle and then 0
    reset <= '1', '0' after T/2;

end arch;
```

counterEx (device under test code)

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counterEx is 
generic( 
    M : natural := 6;
    N : natural := 4 -- N bits are required for M
    );
port(
    clk, reset : in std_logic
);
end entity; 

architecture arch of counterEx is 
    type stateType_moore is (start_moore, count_moore);
    signal state_moore_reg, state_moore_next : stateType_moore;
    signal count_moore_reg, count_moore_next : unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
begin 
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            state_moore_reg <= start_moore;
            count_moore_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            state_moore_reg <= state_moore_next;
            count_moore_reg <= count_moore_next;
        end if; 
    end process;
    
    process(count_moore_reg, state_moore_reg)
    begin 
        case state_moore_reg is
            when start_moore =>
                count_moore_next <= (others => '0');
                state_moore_next <= count_moore;
            when count_moore =>
                count_moore_next <= count_moore_reg  + 1;
                if (count_moore_reg  + 1) = M - 1 then
                    state_moore_next <= start_moore;
                else
                    state_moore_next <= count_moore;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process; 

    --out_moore <= std_logic_vector(count_moore_reg);
end arch;
```

Comment: Can you restart your simulation with Optimization switched off?

Comment: @asdfex I ran vsim -novopt counterEx_Tb.vhd counterEx.vhd, it just opened the files. Is there another way to "Optimize"

Comment: I always use the GUI. There's a checkbox in the start-simulation dialog... Googling for "vsim novopt" gives many links mentioning that it is deprecated and doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any warnings in the console like "entity work.counterEx is unbound"?

Comment: I don't get any errors or warnings and it is optimization is switched off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the testbench by declaring the component, instantiating the DUT properly, used `std.env.stop(0)` and simulated the design long enough. Now it works fine!

You need to **simulate your design long enough** to see the output.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counterEx_tb is
end counterEx_tb;

architecture arch of counterEx_tb is
   
component counterEx is 
generic( 
    M : natural := 6;
    N : natural := 4 -- N bits are required for M
    );
port(
    clk, reset : in std_logic
);
end component counterEx; 
   constant M : integer := 10;
   constant N : integer := 4;
   constant T : time := 20 ns; 

   signal clk, reset : std_logic;  -- input
begin

    unit : counterEx
        generic map (M => M, N => N)
        port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset);

    -- continuous clock
    clock_proc: process 
    begin
        clk <= '1';
        wait for T/2;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for T/2;
    end process clock_proc;


    -- reset = 1 for first clock cycle and then 0
    stim_proc: process
    begin
    reset <= '1', '0' after T/2;
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    wait until falling_edge(clk);
    std.env.stop(0);
    end process stim_proc;
end arch;
```